# Prove the equality $\frac1{(1-x)^4} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^∞ ((n+1)(n+2)(n+3))x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, rational-functions

$$\frac1{(1-x)^4} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^∞ ((n+1)(n+2)(n+3))\frac{x^n}6$$
So. I have been stuck with this series for quite a while and don't know how to prove this equality.

Comment: What is the third derivative of $x \mapsto \frac{1}{1-x}$?

Comment: In general, do you know how to compute terms in a function's Taylor series?

Comment: All of those (n+1)(n+2)(n+3) come from cancelling a factorial in the expansion.